# getMonth problem with Google Sheets javascript

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

getMonth is not a function in this code for Google Sheets:

... Logger.log(ss.getSheetByName("Rendimentos").getRange(aportes-cont,3).getValue().getMonth());

while (ss.getSheetByName("Rendimentos").getRange(aportes-cont,3).getValue().getMonth()===numMes){ ... }

The Logger.log line works perfectly. It shows the number of the month required. But the second line show a message error: getMonth() is not a function.

It just don't make sense the same code works inside the Logger.log, but get stucked inside the while loop.

I don't know what to do.

Comment: _“getMonth() is not a function”_ isn’t an error message. What is the full error message? What debugging have you done so far? Learn about [how to debug small programs](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs when the original cell **does NOT** contain the date. In this case, the `.getMonth()` method tries to determine the month from a value that is not the date.
Try replacing your code with the following:

```
let rangeData = ss.getSheetByName("Rendimentos").getRange('C:C').getValues().flat();    
while (new Date(rangeData[aportes-cont]).getMonth()===numMes){ 
  ... 
}
```

It is also [good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=good%20practice) to reduce the number of times the script accesses the google sheets data - so in the suggested code I first read the data of the entire `column C` once, and then work with the resulting data as elements of an array

Comment: I did like you said. I read all the 'C' column and flatened the array with flat(), but the while loops works only the first time. The code is like below:
var rangeData = ss.getSheetByName("Rendimentos").getRange(1,3,aportes).getValues().flat();

while (new Date(rangeData[aportes-cont]).getMonth()===numMes){
       Logger.log(ss.getSheetByName("Rendimentos").getRange(aportes+1-cont,1).getValue());
        cont=cont-1;
        Logger.log(cont);
      }

The execution goes inside the while loop the first time, but the second time it doesn't go inside.

Comment: Share a copy of your sheet with the data and the script - then maybe the reason will be clear